# Updating User Profile on Registration

Tags: filters, actions, user-registration

I am having trouble getting WP to update a custom profile field when a user registers. Adding the fields works fine. Nothing is inserted into the depositAddress profile field when a user registers.

```
// add profile fields

function coinFields($profileFields) {

// Add new fields
$profileFields['depositAddress']     = 'Deposit Address';
$profileFields['accountBalance']     = 'Account Balance';
$profileFields['totalWinnings']      = 'Total Winnings';
$profileFields['totalLosses']        = 'Total Losses';

return $profileFields;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'coinFields');

// update deposit address

function coinDeposit() {
$current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
$ID = $current_user->ID;

// coin
$coin       =   new jsonRPCClient('http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:14022/');
$account    =   $coin->getaccountaddress($ID);

update_user_meta( $ID, 'depositAddress', $account);

}

add_action('user_register', 'coinDeposit');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dumping your data and you should see the problem:

```
function coinDeposit() {
  $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();

  var_dump($current_user); die;
  update_user_meta( $ID, 'depositAddress', $account);

}
```

The user object is empty. That is because a newly created user is not automatically logged in. There is an email confirmation step, and then login. Until that login, `wp_current_user()` isn't going to give you a user object.

Fortunately, `user_register` is passed the user ID by the Core. Just use that:

```
function coinDeposit($ID) {
  $coin       =   new jsonRPCClient('http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:14022/');
  $account    =   $coin->getaccountaddress($ID);
  update_user_meta( $ID, 'depositAddress', $account);
}

add_action('user_register', 'coinDeposit');
```